# How do I ignore certain tags when parsing xml in Perl?

Tags: xml, perl, tags

I'm parsing a XML file which has, between certain tags, text which I do not want to parse and may even have broken tags. How do I select not to parse that text using one the available modules for xml parsing for Perl?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of a newbie at perl, I'm trying XML::Simple, which gives me errors when i do XMLin("file.xml") of "Opening and ending tag mismatch", which refer to tags inside a specific pair of tags. That's the only code I've got.

Comment: Don't use XML::Simple or any XML parser because they all want valid xml. If HTML is what you have use an HTML parser instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the XML is broken (ie not well-formed), you won't be able to use an XML parser. That's a feature. So you will need to fix it first.

If the XML is well-formed you can use [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig), with the `ignore_elts` option. You'll see the XML as if the ignored elements were never there.

Alternatively, if the XML is "not too broken", you can try [XML::Liberal](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLiberal), which may be able to deal with it. Or not...

And if what you have is XHTML, or HTML, or something close, you can use either XML::LibXML or XML::Twig with the appropriate parsing methods.

Good luck...